# html boostrap navbrand image logo issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I am new to twitter boostrap I am trying to create a play application, I was using navbar-brand for brand name with a logo (elephant image) which I am unable to open in google chrome is there a issue in the code ?

```
</head>
   <header>
       <div class="navbar navbar-default">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exnav">
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
        </div> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="imges/hadoop_ele_copy_copy_copy.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></a>
       </div>
   </header>
```

What I see in chrome on mac books is the below screen shot.

[image]

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Are you sure your image path is correct ..??

Comment: oops wrong path , my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your image is saved in `imges` folder or it's `images/hadoop_ele_copy_copy_copy.jpg`. I think the problem is due to incorrect pathname.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just check your directory name. Make sure that you are keeping image in the correct directory. There is no issue with the code.

<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <div class="navbar navbar-default">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exnav">
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
        </div> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="imges/test.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></a>
       </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```